# How to change query parameters in vue without reloading component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

How do i change the query Parameters without reloading component in Vue with Vue-Router. But pushing new query always reload the component making my api request to rerun

`this.router.replace({query: {name: 'John'} })`

Answer (score 7):

This one works well in Nuxt, so I guess it's totally fine in Vue (even 3) too.

```html
<button @click="$router.replace({ path: $route.path, query: { plan: 'private' } })">test</button>
```

It will push the same path you're currently on, but will change the query param in it.

Taken from the official docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: Can you be more specific what you changed? I have tried explicitly assigning current path (the part `path: $route.path`) but it still reloads the component.

Comment: Fyi, if you configured the router scrollBehavior to always scroll all the way to the top of the page as is often wanted (`return { top: 0 };`), then check before if it's the same path and return `savedPosition` so that a query update does not make your page scroll all the way to the top.