# Update query params in vue(vue-router) without reloading page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a page that has a table that has **Pagination** and **tabs**. Url Looks something like this.

*http://localhost:4000/listPage?tab=all&page=1&items=10*

So I want to update the URL state(query params) every time user paginates and changes tabs without reloading the page only making requests to API's.

Same for changing the tab. Update the query params without reloading the page.

I have tried using the **[history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)** but this will mess with vue-router history and clicking back and forward will no longer take you to the correct page.

```js
history.pushState(
            {},
            null,
            this.$route.path + '?'
            + 'view=' + this.currentView + '&'
            + 'page=' + this.currentPage + '&'
            + 'items=' + this.items
          );
```

Comment: Your question looks pretty much like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66372937/8816585

Answer (score -1):

This should be enough to solve your case

```html
<button 
  @click="$router.replace({ 
    path: $route.path,
    query: { tab: 'all', page: 1, items: 10 } 
  })"
>
  paginate without moving
</button>
```

More info available here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location

Comment: This doesn't work, `router.replace` causes reload/remounting of components

Comment: @Krillko OP mentions only page reload, which this is NOT doing (only updating the Vue router), it is meanwhile indeed impact components' lifecycle. My answer is then correct and you are probably looking for another question overall.